# Background-color sem seguir o max-width

Tags: css, css3

Estipulei uma margem de no máximo 1500px, max-width: 1500px, para o meu site, porém o comportamento do background-color segue até essa margin, não está errado, muito pelo contrário, porém queria deixar a cor da minha div em width 100% porém o resto dos elementos seguindo essa margem.

Teria como realizar isso ou não? Não me ocorre nenhuma outra ideia...

Acho que não teria como. Estava pensando, se tenho que ir acertando as margins na mão usando media-queries?

Comment: Tem algum exemplo pra nos mostrar?

Comment: coloca essa div dentro de uma outra dia com width:100%

Comment: Poderia por um exemplo simplificado do problema para entendermos?

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões pessoal. Dei uma pausa e fui rever linha por linha do meu css e html e encontrei o erro.

Comment: Por isso é sempre importante postar código, leia o Help http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, se fizer perguntas assim, vai gerar respostas aleatórias do qual não irão servir para você e nem servir para nenhum visitante futuro ;)

Comment: Ainda estava com algumas dúvidas, tinha resolvido palhativamente.

Quem estiver com essa dúvida, só seguir o que o andrepaulo falou. funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar a cor de fundo diretamente no body. Segue o exemplo:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Até pode funcionar, porém só tenho essa div que tem essa cor azul e faz uma referência no topo da pagina, o container e o resto da paǵina é branco.

Estou fazendo uma SPA, por isso..

Comment: Entendo. Nesse caso seria necessário um exemplo mais concreto pra tentar entender melhor e poder fazer testes.